# AWS Cognito Authentication Pre-Authentication trigger Lambda function; non existing email address

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I did NOT find a way to capture the email address (username entered by the users in login form) and password in Lambda Function. I have created a Lambda function (nodejs) and triggered it from Cognito Pre Authentication. It get triggered but if the email address does not exist in cognito user pool, `event.request.userAttributes` is empty.

Is there anyone facing the same problem and solved the problem ?

Comment: I'm sure they are there but just to verify when a user signs up are you able to verify that the attributes that you are looking for are saved in the actual user pool?

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't exist, the lambda cannot get its attributes.

If the subsequent problem is that the user attributes object is empty even if it exists, check the IAM Role/Policy attached to the lambda.
It needs the cognito-idp:GetUser to retrieve the UserAttributes.